# My cursor edits a section that is 3 rows above

Tags: editors

I am using sagemath free latex version on PC windows 7. The problem is the editor edits a section that is 3 rows above where the cursor is. This problem happens frequently, whether it is a brand new document, or a preexisting document. I didn't have the problem when I used in a college, but it had only occurred at home. Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Need details.  What operating system and version?  What editor and version?

Comment: LaTeX is the language you're writing, not the program you're writing it in. There's a lot of different editors for writing LaTeX code and compiling it (see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339)). My point is, you really need to provide answers to the question in the above comment by R. Schumacher, as this sort of odd behaviour depends on the editor, not on the LaTeX language.

Comment: As is, I believe that this question is off-topic. The problem relates to the editor and this editor might not be a LaTeX specific editor.

Comment: I am using the editor on sagemath.org. I am using PC windows 7. I am using the sagemath latex editor. I am using the free version.

Comment: when I am viewing the history of the document on sage ( tex.sage.history) the editor functions fine, but not when I am about to edit.

Comment: I would recommend that you take this question to the Sage help forums as this is where you should find someone with expertise on that editor to assist you.   http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/